Binary combinations - rank and unrank
Let's consider a binary value of "n" bits (which consists of only "0"s and "1"s).
We want to pick exactly "r" "1"s of them (and the rest "n-r" are "0"s).
The formula for the total combinations count is -
c = n! / r! (n-r)!

How can we rank and unrank the resulting combination values. (Can we use bit position sum values as a pattern, or there is some other way.)
i.e. out of the above combinations, how can we get the 1st "r" 1s combination, 2nd "r" 1s combination, 3rd "r" 1s combination and so on uptil the final "c" 1s combination.
Is there an efficient way to calculate this for a large "n" and "r" without iterating all values.
Example:
n = 5 bits
r = 2 (pick exactly 2 "1"s out of the given 5 bits, the other bits are "0"s)
c = Total combinations count = 5! / 2! (5-2)! = 5.4.3.2.1 / (2.1) . (3.2.1) = 10


00000
00001
00010
00011 -> r=2 -> rank 1 -> 00001 -> unrank -> 00011
00100
00101 -> r=2 -> rank 2 -> 00010 -> unrank -> 00101
00110 -> r=2 -> rank 3 -> 00011 -> unrank -> 00110
00111
01000
01001 -> r=2 -> rank 4 -> 00100 -> unrank -> 01001
01010 -> r=2 -> rank 5 -> 00101 -> unrank -> 01010
01011
01100 -> r=2 -> rank 6 -> 00110 -> unrank -> 01100
01101
01110
01111

10000
10001 -> r=2 -> rank 7 -> 00111 -> unrank -> 10001
10010 -> r=2 -> rank 8 -> 01000 -> unrank -> 10010
10011
10100 -> r=2 -> rank 9 -> 01001 -> unrank -> 10100
10101
10110
10111
11000 -> r=2 -> rank 10 (= c) -> 01010 -> unrank -> 11000
11001
11010
11011
11100
11101
11110
11111


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

made the question more detailed and clear

To calculate the rank of binary vector $b$, for all the places where there is $1$, add the binomial coefficients $n-1-j\choose s$ where $j$ is the index of the place and $s$ is the count of $1$'s to the right from that place (including the one in that place). And add one to the result (the result would be the zero-based rank). And by the way, the index $j$ is zero-based.
Example: $b=01100$. You sum
$$
{5-1-1\choose 2} + {5-1-2\choose 1} = 5
$$
And add $1$ to get the rank $6$.
The reason why this works is something like this: When you build the vector $b$ from the left up to the index $j$ and have used $r-s$ ones (so there are $s$ left to use), you look what the possible remaining vector can be after you complete the place $j$. There are $n-1-j\choose s$ ways to form the remaining vector when you put $0$ at $j$ and so if you put $1$ you're bigger than all of them so you jump to that rank and start looking again from there. But if you put $0$, you're below the rank and continue without adding that step to the rank.
You're like taking finer and finer steps in the list of all $n,r$ -combinations.
Python-code:
def rank(b):
    n = len(b)
    r = sum(b)
    ret = 0
    onesLeft = r
    for j in range(n):
        if b[j]==1:
            ret += binomial(n-1-j, onesLeft)
            onesLeft -= 1
    return ret+1
    
    
print (rank((0,1,1,0,0)))

Needs the binomial-function (Sage has it, so I didn't include it).
The unrank function is similar. You just kind of reverse the process and subtract binomial coefficients from the rank and put a one/zero depending on whether the "remaining rank" is big enough.
def unrank(k, n, r):
    restRank = k-1
    ret = []
    onesLeft = r
    for j in range(n):
        binoVal = binomial(n-1-j, onesLeft)
        if restRank>=binoVal:
            ret.append(1)
            onesLeft -= 1
            restRank -= binoVal
        else:
            ret.append(0)
    return tuple(ret)

print (unrank(6, 5, 2))

